# Jquery datatables responsiveness not working

Tags: jquery, dom, datatables

I have an issue with the jquery datatable. The scenario is as follows:
I have created a datatable using jquery datatable and in the browser it looks as follows:
[Image in the browser view - click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaJ5K.png)

the initialization for the datatable is done on the basis of id of the table and is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#refresh-on-sort-saved-div').DataTable({
   responsive: true,
   bSort:false,
   scrollY: 300,
   paging: false,
   "searching": false
  });   
 });
```

During the resize of the browser to mobile responsiveness (<768px) the table should be stacked up and should view like this, which is working fine
[Stacked up view - click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rvnw.png)
But this kind of view is not working when i open the same in the actual device or in the simulator directly without resizing the browser, the datatable is not getting responsive at all and is showing in default view.
could some one help me in solving this issue?
I need the datatable to be responsive on page load and when the window is <768px as well on page load without resizing of browser.